# Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $C(H) = \{g ∈ G : gh = hg, \forall h ∈ H\}$. Prove $C(H)$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $C(H) = \{g ∈ G : gh = hg, \forall h ∈ H\}$. Prove $C(H)$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I figured that for this I would use the subgroup test. So if I choose $h=e$, then $g=g$ so $C(H)$ is non-empty. So if I let $a,b \in C(H)$ I need $b^{-1}$ then and to show that $ab^{-1} \in C(H)$. I'm having trouble going from here. I think that I can say that $ga=ag$ and $gb=bg$ which implies that $b^{-1}g = gb^{-1}$. So then $gab^{-1} = ab^{-1}g$ which implies that $ab^{-1} \in C(H)$. This doesn't seem right to me but any help in solving this would be appreciated.

Comment: This is perfect, just make sure you compute $g a b^{-1} = a g b^{-1} = a b^{-1} g$, and that you get from $g b = b g$ to $b^{-1} g = g b^{-1}$ by multiplying on the left and on the right by $b^{-1}$.

Comment: Ok. That is what I did long handed on paper. It just seemed a bit too trivial. I was concerned.

Comment: Don't worry, many things look trivial *a posteriori*.